# Django formset: Unable to save

Tags: django, formset

Trying to setup simple formset, but getting errors 
`'SWDataForm' object has no attribute 'save'`

MODEL

```
class SWData(ValidateOnSaveMixin, models.Model):
    model_serial = models.ForeignKey(SWInfo, related_name='serial_items', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', unique=True)
    deployed = models.BooleanField()

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "SWDATA"

def __str__(self):
    return "{0}".format(self.hostname)
```

VIEW

```
def display_data(request, data, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'web/posted-data.html', dict(data=data, **kwargs))

def swdata(request, *args, **kwargs):
   template = 'web/swdata.html'

   SWDataFormset = modelformset_factory(SWData, fields=('__all__'), extra=1)
   formset = SWDataFormset(request.POST or None)

   if request.method == 'POST':
      print(formset.is_valid())
      if formset.is_valid():
         pprint(formset)
         for form in formset.forms:
            if form.is_valid():
                try:
                    if form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE') and form.instance.pk:
                        form.instance.delete()
                    else:
                        instance = form.save(commit=False)
                        #instance.model_serial = model_serial
                        #print (instance.model_serial)
                        instance.save()
                        messages.success(request, "Successfully")
                except formset.DoesNotExist:
                    messages.error(request, "Database error. Please try again")

        #data = form.cleaned_data
        #return display_data(request, data)
    else:
        formset = SWDataFormset(request.POST or None)
return render(request, template, {'formset': formset})
```

Remove the form and used the modelformset_factory, I was able to save only the last entry in the formset. How to loop thru each formset prefix and save each item?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to save data form from a form, and you can't do that. You need to use the method create of your model. Something like SWDData.objects.create(form).

Comment: is that in the for loop?

Comment: is that in the for loop? Is it possible to give an example, I add in the for loop, but it giving error again, `create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: I have updated the view, now I am able to save it but only the last entry, how to loop thru and save each

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
```

this line is needed when you wants to edit the form.
Now check if it works

Even I also got similar [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60505144/11595669?sem=2)