# unable to save data using django formsets

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, formset

The data entered in the form is not saving in the database and it is not showing any errors.
Iam trying to create an exam with atleast one question, using ExamModelForm and QuestionFormset.
After entering exam details and questions in create_exam_with_questions.html, the create button is not saving the data into the database

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from .forms import ExamModelForm, ExamFormset, QuestionFormset
from .models import Question

def create_exam_with_questions(request):
    template_name = 'school/create_exam_with_questions.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        examform = ExamModelForm(request.GET or None)
        formset = QuestionFormset(queryset=Question.objects.none())
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        examform = ExamModelForm(request.POST)
        formset = QuestionFormset(request.POST)
        if examform.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            # first save this exam, as its reference will be used in `Question`
            exam = examform.save()
            for form in formset:
                # so that `question` instance can be attached.
                question = form.save(commit=False)
                question.exam = exam 
                question.save()
            return redirect("map:map-home")
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'examform': examform,
        'formset': formset,
    })
```

---

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import (formset_factory, modelformset_factory)
from .models import Exam, Question

class ExamModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = ['name', 'section', 'duration', 'subject', 'start', 'teacher']

QuestionFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Question,
    fields=('question', 'ans', 'op2', 'op3', 'op4', ),
    extra=1,
    widgets={'question': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter Question here'
        }),
    'ans': forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter answer here'
        }),
    'op2': forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter option2 here'
        }),
    'op3': forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter option3 here'
        }),
    'op4': forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter option4 here'
        }),
    }
)
```

---

models.py

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    duration = models.TimeField()
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(max_length = 20)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    op2 = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    op3 = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    op4 = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

---

create_exam_with_questions.html

```
{% extends "school/base.html" %}

{% block container %}
{% if heading %}
<h3>{{heading}}</h3>
{% endif %}
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-2">
    <label>{{examform.name.label}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        {{examform.name}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-2">
    <label>{{examform.subject.label}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        {{examform.subject}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-2">
    <label>{{examform.duration.label}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        {{examform.duration}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-2">
    <label>{{examform.teacher.label}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        {{examform.teacher}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-2">
    <label>{{examform.start.label}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        {{examform.start}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-2">
    <label>{{examform.section.label}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        {{examform.section}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="row form-row spacer">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label>{{form.question.label}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.question}}
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.ans}}
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.op2}}
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.op3}}
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.op4}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="row spacer">
    <div class="col-4 offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_js %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
    var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
    var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
    if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
    if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name')
        if(name) {
            name = name.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
            var id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
        if (forValue) {
          forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
          $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
        }
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
    var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
    conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
    .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
    .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
    .html('-');
    return false;
}
function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
    var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
    if (total > 1){
        btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
        var forms = $('.form-row');
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
            $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteForm('form', $(this));
    return false;
});

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace line

```
exam = examform.save()
```

with

```
examform.save()
```

and when saving the question, write

```
for form in formset:
    # so that `question` instance can be attached.
    question = form.save(commit=False)
    question.exam = examform
    question.save()
```

Comment: By doing this, gets  `ValueError: Cannot assign "<ExamModelForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(name; section; subject; teacher) >": " Question.exam" must be a "Exam" instance. `

Answer (score 0):

Unable to populate the initial data and save data using django formsets.

This work totally taken from django funky sheets formset, extar views sets, and it's html except model filed enquire changed.

***view.py***

```py
     
     from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple, CheckboxInput, DateInput
     from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
     from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
     
     from funky_sheets.formsets import HotView
     
     from .models import Assembly
     
     
     def index(request):
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update'))
     
     
     class CreateAssemblyView(HotView):
         model = Assembly
         template_name = 'boards/create.html'
         prefix = 'table'
         checkbox_checked = 'yes'
         checkbox_unchecked = 'no'
         success_url = reverse_lazy('update')
         fields = (
             'id',
             'AssMake',
             'AssModelType',
             'AssFleetSize',
             'AssDateEdit',
     
         )
     
         factory_kwargs = {
             'widgets': {
                 'AssDateEdit': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                 # 'genre': CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                 # 'parents_guide': CheckboxInput(),
             }
         }
     
         hot_settings = {
             # 'columnSorting': 'true',
             'contextMenu': 'true',
             'autoWrapRow': 'true',
             'rowHeaders': 'true',
             'contextMenu': 'true',
             'search': 'true',
             'licenseKey': 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
         }
     
     
     class UpdateAssemblyView(CreateAssemblyView):
         template_name = 'boards/update.html'
         action = 'update'
         button_text = 'Update'
     
         hot_settings = {
             # 'columnSorting': 'true',
             'contextMenu': 'true',
             'autoWrapRow': 'true',
             'rowHeaders': 'true',
             'contextMenu': 'true',
             'search': 'true',
             'licenseKey': 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
         }
```

***models.py***

```py
     from django.db import models
     from django.utils import timezone
     from django.contrib.auth.models import User
     
     
     class Assembly(models.Model):
         AssMake = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
         AssModelType = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
         AssFleetSize = models.IntegerField(null=True)
         AssDateEdit = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
     
         def __str__(self):
             return self.AssModelType
     
     
     class Aircraft(models.Model):
         arcMsn = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
         arcVar = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
         arcRegName = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True, null=True)   
         assembly = models.ForeignKey(Assembly, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
         updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
     
         def __str__(self):
             return self.arcMsn
```

***hot.html***

```py
     {% load static %}
     {% load funky_sheets_tags %}
     
     <link href="{% static 'css/handsontable.full.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"
     
     <form id="form_hot" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return constructFormset();"
     
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ formset.management_form }}
     
       {% if formset.errors %}{% endif %}
     
       {% include errors_template %}
     
       <div id="table_hot"</div
     
       <p
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit"{{ button_text }}</button
       </p
     
     </form
     
     <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"</script
     <script src="{% static 'js/handsontable.full.min.js' %}"</script
     
     <script type="text/javascript"
     
       /* 1. Construct initial data for table from the formset */
     
       var colHeaders = new Array();
       var fieldTypes = new Array();
       var primaryKeys = new Array();
       var data  = new Array();
     
       // Variables supporting "Django Select widget" / "Handsontable dropdown" logic
       var temp = [];
     
       // Iterate through the forms of the formset
       {% for form in formset %}
     
         var row  = new Array();
     
         // Iterate through the fields of the form
         {% for field in form %}
     
           /* CheckboxSelectMultiple widget support for ManyToManyField */
     
           // TODO: Change to switch & function as in constructFormField()?
           {% if field|widget_type == "CheckboxSelectMultiple" %}
     
             {% for choice in field.field.choices %}
               // Only when iterating through the first form in formset
               {% if forloop.parentloop.parentloop.counter == 1 %}
                 colHeaders.push("{{ choice.1 }}"); // Add label to the colHeaders
                 // Extra values needed for construction of m2m checkboxes in constructFormField()
                 fieldTypes.push([ // Add field type to the fieldTypes
                   "m2m {{ field.field.widget.input_type }}",
                   "{{ field.label }}",
                   "{{ forloop.counter0 }}",
                   "{{ choice.0 }}"
                 ]);
               {% endif %}
     
               // field.value is a list of 'ids' of related objects in m2m field
               // choice.0 is an 'id' of single related object
               {% if choice.0 in field.value|int_list %}
                 row.push("{{ checkbox_checked }}");
               {% else %}
                 row.push("{{ checkbox_unchecked }}");
               {% endif %}
     
             {% endfor %}
     
           /* Select widget */
     
           // TODO: Add comments
           {% elif field|widget_type == "Select" %}
     
             var choiceValues = [];
             var choiceStrings = [];
     
             var cellWidgetChoiceValues = [];
             var cellWidgetChoiceStrings = [];
     
             {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 1 %}
               colHeaders.push("{{ field.label }}");
     
               if (temp.length === 0) {
                 temp.push("{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}");
               }
     
               {% for choice in field.field.choices %}
                 cellWidgetChoiceValues.push("{{ choice.0 }}");
                 cellWidgetChoiceStrings.push("{{ choice.1 }}");
               {% endfor %}
     
               temp.push([cellWidgetChoiceValues, cellWidgetChoiceStrings]);
               fieldTypes.push(temp);
     
             {% endif %}
     
             {% for choice in field.field.choices %}
               choiceValues.push("{{ choice.0 }}");
               choiceStrings.push("{{ choice.1 }}");
             {% endfor %}
     
             {% if field.value %}
               // Get index of selected choice in choiceValues
               var index = choiceValues.indexOf("{{ field.value }}");
               // Push string at index in choiceStrings to the row
               row.push(choiceStrings[index]);
             {% else %}
               row.push("");
             {% endif %}
     
           /* Other widgets: TextInput, NumberInput, URLInput, DateInput, CheckboxInput */
     
           {% else %}
     
             if ("{{ field.label }}" != "Id" && "{{ field.label }}" != "Delete"){
     
               // Only when iterating through the first form in formset
               {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 1 %}
                 colHeaders.push("{{ field.label }}"); // Add label to the colHeaders
                 fieldTypes.push([ // Add field type to the fieldTypes
                   "{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}"
                 ]);
               {% endif %}
     
               // Add value to the row
     
               // Input with value
               {% if field.value %}
     
                 // URLInput
                 {% if field.field.widget.input_type == "url" %}
                   row.push("<a href={{ field.value }} target='_blank'{{ field.value }}</a");
                 // CheckboxInput
                 {% elif field.field.widget.input_type == "checkbox" %}
                   row.push("{{ checkbox_checked }}");
                 // Other widgets
                 {% else %}
                   row.push("{{ field.value }}");
                 {% endif %}
     
               // Inputs without value
               {% else %}
     
                 // CheckboxInput
                 {% if field.field.widget.input_type == "checkbox" %}
                   row.push("{{ checkbox_unchecked }}");
                 // Other widgets
                 {% else %}
                   row.push("");
                 {% endif %}
     
               {% endif %}
     
             } else if ("{{ field.label }}" == "Id") {
               // TODO: Why?
               // Add value to the primaryKeys
               primaryKeys.push("{{ field.value }}");
             };
     
           {% endif %}
     
         {% endfor %}
     
         // Add row to the data
         data.push(row);
     
         // Debug logs
         // console.log(row);
     
       {% endfor %}
     
       /* 2. Construct & fill in formset fields */
     
       var total_non_empty_rows = 0;
     
       function constructFormset() {
         // Get data from instantiated Handsontable
         var tableData = hot.getData();
     
         // Iterate through tableData
         // Construct form from each row (i=row number)
         for(var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
           var rowTemp = tableData[i];
           var row = rowTemp.map(setBooleansArray);
           var pk = "";
     
           // Get primary key
           if (i < primaryKeys.length){
             pk = primaryKeys[i]
           }
     
           // Add primary key value or empty string
           {% if action == "update" %}
             var input_id = "{{ formset.prefix }}-" + i + "-id";
             $("#form_hot").append(
               '<input id="id_' + input_id
               + '" name="' + input_id
               + '" type="hidden" value="' + pk +'" /'
             );
           {% endif %}
     
           // Set empty rows for deletion
           if (row.isNull()){
             var input_id = "{{formset.prefix}}-" + i + "-DELETE";
             $('#form_hot').append(
               '<input id="id_' + input_id
               + '" name="' + input_id
               + '" type="hidden" value="on" /'
             );
           }
           // Add fields to the form of a formset for each element of a row in tableData
           // (i=row number, j=column number)
           else {
             for(var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
               constructFormField(i, j, fieldTypes[j], row);
             }
             total_non_empty_rows += 1;
           }
         }
         // Set total number of forms
         var input_id = "id_{{ formset.prefix }}-TOTAL_FORMS";
         $('#' + input_id).val(total_non_empty_rows);
     
         return true;
       }
     
       /* 3. Helper functions */
     
       // 3.1. Check if an array contains only empty strings
       Array.prototype.isNull = function (){
         return this.join().replace(/,/g,"").length === 0;
       };
     
       // 3.2. Construct form field (i=row number, j=column number)
       function constructFormField(i, j, fieldType, row) {
         var partialName = colHeaders[j].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"_");
         var fieldName = "{{ formset.prefix }}-" + i + "-" + partialName;
         var fieldString = "";
     
         var value = row[j];
     
         if (value == null) {
           value = "";
         }
     
         switch(fieldType[0]) {
           case "select": // select field
             // TODO: Add comments
             // Get index of selected choice in choiceStrings
             var index = fieldType[j][1].indexOf(value);
             // Get value at index in choiceValues
             value = fieldType[j][0][index];
     
             fieldString = "<select id='id_" + fieldName
                           + "' name='" + fieldName
                           + "' style='visibility: hidden;'"
                           + "<option value='" + value +"' selected</option"
                           + "</select";
             break;
           case "m2m checkbox": // m2m checkbox field
             if (value == true) {
               var fieldLabel, count = "";
               var tablePrefix = "{{ formset.prefix }}-" + i + "-";
               var fieldLabel = fieldType[1].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"_");
               var count = fieldType[2];
               value = fieldType[3];
     
               fieldString = "<input id=id_'" + tablePrefix + fieldLabel + "_" + count
                             + "' name='" + tablePrefix + fieldLabel
                             + "' type='hidden' value='" + value + "' /";
             }
             break;
           case "url": // url field
             if (value.indexOf("href=") != -1) {
               value = $("<div").append(value).find("a").attr("href");
             }
     
             fieldString = "<input id=id_'" + fieldName
                           + "' name='" + fieldName
                           + "' type='hidden' value='" + value + "' /";
     
             break;
           default: // text, number, checkbox fields
             fieldString = "<input id=id_'" + fieldName
                           + "' name='" + fieldName
                           + "' type='hidden' value='" + value + "' /";
         }
     
         return $('#form_hot').append(fieldString);
       }
     
       // 3.3. Custom Handsontable HtmlRendered, which removes null from empty url inputs
       function cleanHtmlRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties){
         Handsontable.renderers.HtmlRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
         if (td.innerHTML === "null") {
           td.innerHTML = "";
         }
       }
       Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer("cleanHtmlRenderer", cleanHtmlRenderer);
     
       // 3.4. Construct Handsontable columns based on fieldTypes
       var cellWidget = function(item, index) {
         if (item[0] == "checkbox" || item[0] == "m2m checkbox") {
           return {
             type: "checkbox",
             checkedTemplate: "{{ checkbox_checked }}",
             uncheckedTemplate: "{{ checkbox_unchecked }}",
           };
         } else if (item[0] == "select") {
           return {
             type: "dropdown",
             source: item[index][1]
           };
         } else if (item[0] == "date") {
           return {
             type: "date",
             dateFormat: "{{ date_format }}"
           };
         } else if (item[0] == "url") {
           return {
             renderer: "cleanHtmlRenderer"
           };
         } else {
           return {};
         }
       }
     
       // 3.5. Change string 'true' or 'false' to js booleans
     
       // On paste from clipboard
       var setBooleansArray = function(item, index) {
         if (item == "{{ checkbox_checked }}") {
           return true;
         } else if (item == "{{ checkbox_unchecked }}") {
           return false;
         } else {
           return item;
         }
       }
     
       // On getting hotSettings passed in from HotView
       var setBooleansObject = function(obj) {
         for (var key in obj) {
           if (obj[key] == "true") {
             obj[key] = true;
           } else if (obj[key] == "false") {
             obj[key] = false;
           }
         }
       }
     
       /* 4. Construct Handsontable */
     
       var container = document.getElementById("table_hot");
       // Construct columns & cell types based on fieldTypes
       var columns = fieldTypes.map(cellWidget);
     
       // Debug logs
       // console.log(colHeaders);
       // console.log(fieldTypes);
       // console.log("{{ date_format }}");
       // console.log(columns);
     
       // Default hotSettings
       var hotSettings = {
         data: data,
         colHeaders: colHeaders,
         columns: columns
       };
     
       // Get hotSettings passed in from HotView
       var extraHotSettings = {{ hot_settings|safe }};
       setBooleansObject(extraHotSettings);
     
       // Extend hotSettings with extraHotSettings
       var hotSettings = $.extend(hotSettings, extraHotSettings);
     
       var hot = new Handsontable(container, hotSettings);
     
       $("#HandsontableCopyPaste").css("visibility", "hidden");
     
     </script>
```

From `django.conf` import settings from `django.db` import migrations, models import `django.db.models.deletion` import `django.utils.timezone`.

***migrations***

```py
 from boards.models import Assembly
 
 def add_assembly(apps, schema_editor):
     assembly_one = Assembly.objects.create(
         AssMake='B767',
         AssModelType='Boeing',
         AssFleetSize = 3,
         AssDateEdit='2023-01-16',
 
     )
     assembly_two = Assembly.objects.create(
         AssMake='A350',
         AssModelType='Airbus',
         AssFleetSize=19,
         AssDateEdit='2023-02-16',
     )
     assembly_three = Assembly.objects.create(
         AssMake='B777',
         AssModelType='Boeing',
         AssFleetSize=19,
         AssDateEdit='2023-03-16',
     )
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
 
      initial = True
 
     dependencies = [
         migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
     ] migrations.CreateModel(
             name='Assembly',
             fields=[
                 ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                 ('AssMake', models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)),
                 ('AssModelType', models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)),
                 ('AssFleetSize', models.IntegerField(null=True)),
                 ('AssDateEdit', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, null=True)),
             ],
         ),
 
 
 migrations.CreateModel(
             name='Aircraft',
             fields=[
                 ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                 ('arcMsn', models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)),
                 ('arcVar', models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)),
                 ('arcRegName', models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, unique=True)),
                 
             ],
         ),
```